# How to close the Facebook pop-up login window after the user Connects?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Below is my code. For some reason, after the user logs into the little pop-up window, the little window will redirect back to '/" with a lot of session JSON junk at the end of the URL.

**How do I make it so that the little window closes, and my parent window refreshes?**

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US" type="text/javascript"></script>

<fb:login-button v="2" onlogin='window.location("/test");' size="medium">Connect</fb:login-button>
<script type="text/javascript">FB.init("XXXXX",'/xd_receiver.htm');</script>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If anyone is having this problem in June 2011, FB recently introduced a bug which stops the window closing in IE 7, 8 & 9. See here: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18405

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I solved it. It was to do with my settings in FAcebook's page.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you tell me what did you change in the settings to make it work?

Comment: Maybe be a little more descriptive on how you solved the problem next time please...

Answer (score 3):

I just solved a similar issue, that when you login with the Facebook login popup window, and it closes, the page didn't refresh.

My Facebook APP wasn't properly configured. Just go to your application settings in Facebook and specify the correct Site URL (under the Web Site section). If you are testing it locally you can put http://localhost/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

**Page Reloading**

Try setting the `reloadIfSessionStateChanged` flag for `FB.init`.  For example,

```
FB.init(  "myAPIkey", 
          "path/to/xd_receiver.htm",
          {"reloadIfSessionStateChanged": true}
       );
```

From the Facebook API

> *reloadIfSessionStateChanged*
>
> bool - If the value is true, Facebook
>   will monitor changes in session state
>   and reload the current page if the
>   session state changes. This option is
>   convenient for an implementation that
>   needs to reload the page whenever
>   session state change in order to
>   generate different content from server
>   side.

For more info check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Facebook.init

**Popup Not Closing**

I've found that you may have issues with your popup window not closing if your `path/to/xd_receiver.html` is incorrect, or if your `onlogin` function for your Connect Button is undefined, so be sure to double check those.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onlogin attribute this way:

```
onlogin="document.location.href=document.location.href;"
```

This will be executed by the opener (refreshing the page).
If you remove the onlogin attribute the pop up will also close, but the page below do not refresh.

I wrote a tutorial about integrating a community with facebook connect, you can read it [here](http://www.barattalo.it/facebook-connect-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a random 'h' in your code. Could this be messing with the JS functionality?

```
FB.init("XXXXX",'/xd_receiver.htm'h);
                                  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

My popup wasn't closing (when posting to a feed) because I didn't have the channel.html file in the right place. After doing the post it redirects to the channel.html file in order (partly) to close the popup - so not having it in the right place meant it didn't close.